# Stop asking permission again and again in J2ME

Tags: java-me

I am using Location API and `HttpConnection`  in my J2ME Application which keeps tracking updated location and showing image of Google Map, So it is asking for user permission repeatedly.

How to avoid this ?

Comment: Please concretize your question, which Operating System? Are you sure you are using JavaME and not Android (those are very different things)? Show us some code, what have you tried?

Comment: cr.setHorizontalAccuracy(5); 
             cr.setVerticalAccuracy(5);
             
             lp= LocationProvider.getInstance(cr);  
            l = lp.getLocation(4000);if(lp.getState()==LocationProvider.AVAILABLE)
        {  
            c = l.getQualifiedCoordinates();   
        img= Image.createImage(getMap(18.553656, 73.80689, width, height, zoom));
       }

Comment: I had put such code in thread so that it runs in background and update location automatically

Comment: Security popups can only be killed by signing your app. That requires a certificate that'll cost you $300 a year.

Answer (score 2):

The Permission you are talking about it a security permissions. To remove these security permission message you need to sign your mobile application with some certified authority like [Verysign](http://www.verisigninc.com/?cmp=SEMG02:01I) or [Thawte](https://www.thawte.com/lp-sem/?sl=t29100223210313007&gclid=COCY5pqI1rYCFYsm6wodXi0AGQ)

You need to purchase a licensing certificate from the site. Once you get the certificate ( which is valid of a year and cost is around 20K India Rupee ) you can sign any many applications as you want.

J2ME architecture is made to protect, not to run all the API without permission. The high level 
API's like create/read/delete file, make http request,Location API etc must require your application to be sign to avoid the security messages.